# jQuery window scroll event. For every XX pixels scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, scroll

I am using the excellent jQuery Reel plugin (http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) for a project. I would like to bind to the window scroll event, so when the user scrolls down the page the plugin advances 1 frame for say every 10px scrolled, if the user scrolls up the animation is reversed.

The plugin has methods I can pass the values to no problem and I know how to bind to the window scroll event. What I am struggling with is the last.

How can I use jQuery/JavaScript to say for every 10 pixels scrolled in any vertical direction advance 1 frame in the animation? I know I can store the window scroll in a variable but I'm unsure how to say every time it hits a multiple of 10 advance one frame.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT

Thanks to help of the users below I worked out a solution. As follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    windowScrollCount   = $(this).scrollTop();
    animationFrame      = Math.round(windowScrollCount / 100);
});
```

So here I am getting the scrolled distance in windowScrollCount, translating it into frames in animationFrame and setting it back with .reel("frame", animationFrame); I am actually doing this for every 100 frames as every 10 was to quick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to help of codef0rmer and noShowP I worked out a solution. As follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    windowScrollCount   = $(this).scrollTop();
    animationFrame      = Math.round(windowScrollCount / 100);
});
```

So here I am getting the scrolled distance in windowScrollCount, translating it into frames in animationFrame and setting it back with .reel("frame", animationFrame); I am actually doing this for every 100 frames as every 10 was to quick.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm wrong then you might want this:

```
var jump = 500;  // consider this is your 10px 
window.scrollHeight = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
   console.log($(this).scrollTop());
   var diff = $(this).scrollTop() - window.scrollHeight;
    if (diff >= jump) {
       window.scrollHeight = $(this).scrollTop();   
       console.log('reload frame');
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Dyd6h/

Comment: codef0rmer thanks for your reply. Thats not quite what I want although I'm starting to understand now how I can achieve it. Basically every time scrollTop hits 10 then 20 then 30 etc advance one frame.

Comment: codef0rmer thanks for the help, I have worked it out please see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You could possible have a sticky element to the top of your page,

> position: fixed; top 0; left: 0;

(hidden if you like).

And then when you are scrolling you can monitor its offset:

```
$('element').offset().top
```

You can then see how far down the page you have scrolled, so every time they scroll see what its top value is and trigger events appropiately?

EDIT:

I've set up a little JSfiddle with a start of what I think you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/qJhRz/3/

Im just calculating the frame you need to be on and storing that in a variable. Is it anything like what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but thats not what I'm wanting. I have updated the last paragraph above to make the requirement clearer.

Comment: I've never used reel before, do you already know how to make it advance one frame and you just need to know how to call those events every time 10px is scrolled?

Comment: I think you are on the right lines here I can reference the frame count in a variable. I just didn't understand how to when the scrollTop hits 10 then 20 then 30 etc advance one frame (or add one to the frame variable). I'm starting to understand now thanks for the help

Comment: noShowP thanks for the help, I have worked it out please see my answer above.

Comment: No worries, looks like you've used my method, glad it worked for you :)