# Do something for every n pixel the window is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to do something for every 27px the window is scrolled. I've written the following code, placed inside a `scroll` event handler:

```
scrollSpy++
if (scrollSpy > 27) {
    scrollSpy = 0;
    console.log("27px scrolled");
}
```

But somehow it's not working.
When I scroll really slow, the events are triggered quite regularly (although I can't tell if it's really after 27px), but when I scroll fast, the event seems to be triggered random/not at all.

I guess the error lies in the assumption that the `scroll` event is triggered for every px scrolled, because that would be a requirement for the `scrollSpy++` method to work.

But of course, I am not sure if that's really the error. How do I do this correctly?

Note: This question is no duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428690/jquery-window-scroll-event-for-every-xx-pixels-scrolled), because there the accepted answer is geared towards reel.

---

Edit:
So based on the answers, I've written this if statement:

```
if (window.pageYOffset % 27 === 0) {
    // do something
}
```

But its still not working. When I scroll fast the function fails. So it has something to do with how the `scroll` event is triggered. Do you know any solution for this? `setTimeout` or `setInterval` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption. You should check how much

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop
```

changes between calls of the function. If it increases, the user is scrolling down, and vice versa.

Use this knowledge to determine when to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: Hey, based on your answer I've edited my post, maybe you can have a look at it?

Comment: Your code relies on the 27-pixel mark being passed through exactly. This is not the case. You should save `Math.floor((document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.body.scrollTop)/27)` and see if it changes.

Comment: Ah ok, but the strange thing is, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is always zero.

Comment: Some browsers use `documentElement`, some use `body`. By adding them up you get a cross-browser result.

Answer (score 1):

No, `scroll` events aren’t triggered for every pixel scrolled. Anyways, you can just use `window.pageYOffset` instead, with fallbacks as necessary as described in [the MDN documentation for `pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY), and check in which direction and by how much that value changes on each `scroll` event.

Comment: Hey, I've incorporated your answer in an if-statement I've added to my question, maybe you can take a look at it?